# Format multiple values as a list

Tags: java, string

Is there a simple enough method to display several values like I did but only display non-zero values? (I don't really know how to explain this and my English is not very good so I'll feed you with examples so you understand better what I'm trying to achieve.)

*Examples* :

- Input : galleons=0, sickles=0, knuts=5.
- Output (String) : "5 knuts."

---

- Input : galleons=3, sickles=0, knuts=5.
- Output (String) : "3 galleons and 5 knuts."

---

- Input : galleons=3, sickles=4, knuts=5.
- Output (String) : "3 galleons, 4 sickles and 5 knuts."

## Actual code:

```
public String knutsToString(int knuts) {
  int galleons = knuts / 493;
  int sickles = knuts / 29 - galleons * 17;
  knuts -= sickles * 29 + galleons * 493;

  return galleons + " galleons, " + sickles + " sickles and " + knuts + " knuts.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do:

```java
static void print(int galleons, int sickles, int knuts) {
    StringJoiner buf = new StringJoiner(", ");
    add(buf, galleons, "galleon", "galleons");
    add(buf, sickles, "sickle", "sickles");
    add(buf, knuts, "knut", "knuts");
    String text = buf.toString();
    int idx = text.lastIndexOf(',');
    if (idx != -1)
        text = text.substring(0, idx) + " and" + text.substring(idx + 1);
    System.out.println(text.isEmpty() ? "You are broke" : text);
}

private static void add(StringJoiner buf, int value, String singular, String plural) {
    if (value != 0)
        buf.add(value + " " + (value == 1 ? singular : plural));
}
```

*Test*

```java
print(0, 0, 0);
print(0, 0, 5);
print(3, 0, 5);
print(3, 4, 5);
```

*Output*

```
You are broke
5 knuts
3 galleons and 5 knuts
3 galleons, 4 sickles and 5 knuts
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/ghEOpb) for demo.

Answer (score 1):

For a short version, how about...

```
private static String getAmounts(int galleons, int sickles, int knuts) {
    String[] array = {nonZero(galleons,"galleon"),nonZero(sickles,"sickle"),nonZero(knuts,"knut")};
    String ans = Arrays.asList(array).stream().filter(s -> !s.equals("")).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    int comma = ans.lastIndexOf(", ");
    return comma==-1?ans:ans.substring(0, comma) + " and" + ans.substring(comma + 1);
}

private static String nonZero(int i, String text) {
    if (i == 0) return "";
    else if (i == 1) return i+" "+text;
    else return i+" "+text+"s";
}
```

Comment: Second example in question shows that output should be `"3 galleons and 5 knuts."`, but that code returns `"3 galleons, 5 knuts"`. Part of the complexity of the question is handling `,` vs `and`, so this answer is not useful. --- Also, although it happens to work here, using `s != ""` is really bad form.

Comment: Good catches @Andreas. I put fixes in for them as well as adding code for singular vs plural.